# How to put CREATE TRIGGER into TRY-CATCH block with TRANSACTION?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, try-catch, database-trigger

I'm not advanced programmer in SQL and maybe my question is silly, but I haven't found an answer in google. We have some SQL construction for implementing packages of changes:

```
...
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    <User Code Is Here>
    ...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ...
END CATCH;
...
```

How can I put the chain of CREATE TRIGGER blocks instead of `<User Code Is Here>` without errors:

```
-- Table1
CREATE TRIGGER trTable1_Dates ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   ...
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
GO
...
-- TableN
CREATE TRIGGER trTableN_Dates ON dbo.TableN
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   ...
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
GO
```

The purpose is to create all triggers or nothing and print message in CATCH block of code if fails.

**Edited**

The errors are:

1. On first trigger's `BEGIN`: *SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.  Expecting EXTERNAL.*
2. After first trigger, on `GO`: *SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.*
3. `END TRY`: *SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'.  Expecting CONVERSATION.*
4. `END CATCH`: *SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'CATCH'.  Expecting CONVERSATION.*

Comment: Doesnt it work if you just add all the create... scripts at the place of <user code is here>?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis No, it doesn't. I'll write an errors in **Edited** section

Comment: What platform and version are you using? I haven't seen this kind of errors on sql server...

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 (v 15.9.9) or SSMS v 17.9 - there are errors in both environments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run each `create trigger` statement in a separate scope/batch (because it has to be the first statement in the batch). So you'll have to escape any quotes in the trigger definitions too:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    exec sp_executesql N'CREATE TRIGGER trTable1_Dates ON dbo.Table1
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       //An empty string in here has to be '''' to escape the quotes
       SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END'
    
    exec sp_executesql N'CREATE TRIGGER trTableN_Dates ON dbo.TableN
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       ...
       SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ...
END CATCH;
```

Transactions are orthogonal to batches and nested scopes, so the transaction covers all activity that occurs inside each `EXEC` too.

Comment: Damien, why does putting 'GO' between the trigger creation queries not work? Strangely, I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'`, but the second(!!) trigger gets created.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - Because `GO` isn't a T-SQL construct - it tells client tools how to break a script apart into batches to submit to the server. `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks can't cross batch boundaries. Your second batch (after the `GO`) starts with `CREATE TRIGGER` so the trigger gets created.